# Unsure why mkdir function isn't working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, mkdir

So I've got localhost and I'm building my web app on codeigniter. I've got this as part of a function to make a directory:

```
mkdir(base_url() . 'assets/img/' . $_POST['cells']['slug'] . '/');
```

It should create the directory:

`http://localhost/sitedirectory/assets/img/slug/`

I don't know why that's not working.

Comment: Filesystem calls such as mkdir() should use filesystem references, not url references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `base_url` will be an HTTP URL. You can't create directories on HTTP URLs, you have to create them on your filesystem. (Your web server can then map the directories on to HTTP URLs)

Comment: Ah, so just localhost/sitedirectory/assets/img/slug/ would be fine?

Comment: It is unlikely that the current working directory will contain a subdirectory called "localhost". You need to do something appropriate for the directory structure of your file system.

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm not too well versed in how directories and filesystems work. If I'm understanding correctly, getcwd() returns /sitedirectory/, so I would have to build the string from there - so I would simply need to call mkdir('/assets/img/slug/)?

Comment: If you start it with a `/` then you'll go back to the file system root.

Answer (score 2):

In stead of

```
mkdir(base_url() . 'assets/img/' . $_POST['cells']['slug'] . '/');
```

You have to use :-

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'FOlder_Name/assets/img/' . $_POST['cells']['slug'] . '/');
```

And Make sure where you want to make directory, its permission should be "777".

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like this:

```
mkdir(APPPATH . 'assets/img/' . $_POST['cells']['slug'] . '/');
```

Here are some other possibilities

```
// System Directory Path
SYSDIR

// Application Directory Path
APPPATH
```

Also take a look at the Path Helper!